# get sequence number for simulated rtp packet

Tags: java, network-programming, voip, rtp

> i try to make my own RTP packet with java, and i have send my packet
>   together with other VoIP's RTP packet.

PROBLEM :

> in receiver, my packet was detected as packet loss because my packet
>   did'nt have sequence number series with VoIP's RTP packet.

QUESTION:

> how can i get series sequence number for my simulated rtp packet?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence number can be found in the 3rd and 4th octet of the RTP packet.

RTP sequence numbers must be in series. If you are trying to insert your RTP packets into another stream sent by another application the receiving application will detect either out of sequence packets (if the numbers are not in series) or duplicate packets (if the sequence number is the same). In both cases this will most likely result in dropped packets.

See RFC 3550 for the full details (specifically appendix A which describes algorithms including packet loss detection)

Answer (score 1):

See below the implementation of Mobicents project.

```
/*
 * JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
 * Copyright 2011, Red Hat, Inc. and individual contributors
 * by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the distribution for a
 * full listing of individual contributors.
 *
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
 * Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
 * 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
 */

package org.mobicents.media.server.impl.rtp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

/**
 * A data packet consisting of the fixed RTP header, a possibly empty list of
 * contributing sources, and the payload data. Some underlying protocols may
 * require an encapsulation of the RTP packet to be defined. Typically one
 * packet of the underlying protocol contains a single RTP packet,
 * but several RTP packets may be contained if permitted by the encapsulation
 * method
 *
 * @author Oleg Kulikov
 * @author amit bhayani
 */
public class RtpPacket implements Serializable {

    //underlying buffer
    private ByteBuffer buffer;

    /**
     * Creates new instance of RTP packet.
     *
     * @param capacity the maximum available size for packet.
     * @param allocateDirect if false then packet will use backing array to hold
     * raw data and if true the direct buffer will be allocated
     */
    public RtpPacket(int capacity, boolean allocateDirect) {        
        buffer = allocateDirect ? 
            ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(capacity) :
            ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);
    }

    /**
     * Provides access to the underlying buffer.
     *
     * @return the underlying buffer instance.
     */
    protected ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    /**
     * Verion field.
     *
     * This field identifies the version of RTP. The version defined by
     * this specification is two (2). (The value 1 is used by the first
     * draft version of RTP and the value 0 is used by the protocol
     * initially implemented in the "vat" audio tool.)
     *
     * @return the version value.
     */
    public int getVersion() {
        return (buffer.get(0) & 0xC0) >> 6;
    }

    /**
     * Countributing source field.
     *
     * The CSRC list identifies the contributing sources for the
     * payload contained in this packet. The number of identifiers is
     * given by the CC field. If there are more than 15 contributing
     * sources, only 15 may be identified. CSRC identifiers areinserted by
     * mixers, using the SSRC identifiers of contributing
     * sources. For example, for audio packets the SSRC identifiers of
     * all sources that were mixed together to create a packet are
     * listed, allowing correct talker indication at the receiver.
     *
     * @return synchronization source.
     */
    public int getContributingSource() {
        return buffer.get(0) & 0x0F;
    }

    /**
     * Padding indicator.
     *
     * If the padding bit is set, the packet contains one or more
     * additional padding octets at the end which are not part of the
     * payload. The last octet of the padding contains a count of how
     * many padding octets should be ignored. Padding may be needed by
     * some encryption algorithms with fixed block sizes or for
     * carrying several RTP packets in a lower-layer protocol data
     * unit.
     *
     * @return true if padding bit set.
     */
    public boolean hasPadding() {
        return (buffer.get(0) & 0x20) == 0x020;
    }

    /**
     * Extension indicator.
     *
     * If the extension bit is set, the fixed header is followed by
     * exactly one header extension.
     *
     * @return true if extension bit set.
     */
    public boolean hasExtensions() {
        return (buffer.get(0) & 0x10) == 0x010;
    }

    /**
     * Marker bit.
     *
     * The interpretation of the marker is defined by a profile. It is
     * intended to allow significant events such as frame boundaries to
     * be marked in the packet stream. A profile may define additional
     * marker bits or specify that there is no marker bit by changing
     * the number of bits in the payload type field
     *
     * @return true if marker set.
     */
    public boolean getMarker() {
        return (buffer.get(1) & 0xff & 0x80) == 0x80;
    }

    /**
     * Payload type.
     *
     * This field identifies the format of the RTP payload and
     * determines its interpretation by the application. A profile
     * specifies a default static mapping of payload type codes to
     * payload formats. Additional payload type codes may be defined
     * dynamically through non-RTP means
     *
     * @return integer value of payload type.
     */
    public int getPayloadType() {
        return (buffer.get(1) & 0xff & 0x7f);
    }

    /**
     * Sequence number field.
     *
     * The sequence number increments by one for each RTP data packet
     * sent, and may be used by the receiver to detect packet loss and
     * to restore packet sequence. The initial value of the sequence
     * number is random (unpredictable) to make known-plaintext attacks
     * on encryption more difficult, even if the source itself does not
     * encrypt, because the packets may flow through a translator that
     * does.
     *
     * @return the sequence number value.
     */
    public int getSeqNumber() {
        

        short sn = buffer.getShort(2);      
        return (sn & 0xffff);

    }

    /**
     * Timestamp field.
     *
     * The timestamp reflects the sampling instant of the first octet
     * in the RTP data packet. The sampling instant must be derived
     * from a clock that increments monotonically and linearly in time
     * to allow synchronization and jitter calculations.
     * The resolution of the clock must be sufficient for the
     * desired synchronization accuracy and for measuring packet
     * arrival jitter (one tick per video frame is typically not
     * sufficient).  The clock frequency is dependent on the format of
     * data carried as payload and is specified statically in the
     * profile or payload format specification that defines the format,
     * or may be specified dynamically for payload formats defined
     * through non-RTP means. If RTP packets are generated
     * periodically, the nominal sampling instant as determined from
     * the sampling clock is to be used, not a reading of the system
     * clock. As an example, for fixed-rate audio the timestamp clock
     * would likely increment by one for each sampling period.  If an
     * audio application reads blocks covering 160 sampling periods
     * from the input device, the timestamp would be increased by 160
     * for each such block, regardless of whether the block is
     * transmitted in a packet or dropped as silent.
     *
     * The initial value of the timestamp is random, as for the sequence
     * number. Several consecutive RTP packets may have equal timestamps if
     * they are (logically) generated at once, e.g., belong to the same
     * video frame. Consecutive RTP packets may contain timestamps that are
     * not monotonic if the data is not transmitted in the order it was
     * sampled, as in the case of MPEG interpolated video frames. (The
     * sequence numbers of the packets as transmitted will still be
     * monotonic.)
     *
     * @return timestamp value
     */
    public long getTimestamp() {
        return ((long)(buffer.get(4) & 0xff) << 24) |
               ((long)(buffer.get(5) & 0xff) << 16) |
               ((long)(buffer.get(6) & 0xff) << 8)  |
               ((long)(buffer.get(7) & 0xff));
    }

    /**
     * Synchronization source field.
     *
     * The SSRC field identifies the synchronization source. This
     * identifier is chosen randomly, with the intent that no two
     * synchronization sources within the same RTP session will have
     * the same SSRC identifier. Although the
     * probability of multiple sources choosing the same identifier is
     * low, all RTP implementations must be prepared to detect and
     * resolve collisions.  Section 8 describes the probability of
     * collision along with a mechanism for resolving collisions and
     * detecting RTP-level forwarding loops based on the uniqueness of
     * the SSRC identifier. If a source changes its source transport
     * address, it must also choose a new SSRC identifier to avoid
     * being interpreted as a looped source.
     * 
     * @return the sysncronization source 
     */
    public long getSyncSource() {
        return ((long)(buffer.get(8) & 0xff) << 24) |
               ((long)(buffer.get(9) & 0xff) << 16) |
               ((long)(buffer.get(10) & 0xff) << 8) |
               ((long)(buffer.get(11) & 0xff));
    }

    /**
     * The number of bytes transmitted by RTP in a packet.
     *
     * @return the number of bytes.
     */
    public int getPayloadLength() {
        return buffer.limit() - 12;
    }

    /**
     * Reads the data transported by RTP in a packet, for example
     * audio samples or compressed video data.
     *
     * @param buff the buffer used for reading
     * @param offset the initial offset inside buffer.
     */
    public void getPayload(byte[] buff, int offset) {
        buffer.position(12);
        buffer.get(buff, offset, buffer.limit() - 12);
    }

    /**
     * Encapsulates data into the packet for transmission via RTP.
     *
     * @param mark mark field
     * @param payloadType payload type field.
     * @param seqNumber sequence number field
     * @param timestamp timestamp field
     * @param ssrc synchronization source field
     * @param data data buffer
     * @param offset offset in the data buffer
     * @param len the number of bytes
     */
    public void wrap(boolean mark, int payloadType, int seqNumber, long timestamp, long ssrc, byte[] data, int offset, int len) {
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.rewind();

        //no extensions, paddings and cc
        buffer.put((byte)0x80);

        byte b = (byte) (payloadType);
        if (mark) {
            b = (byte) (b | 0x80);
        }

        buffer.put(b);

        //sequence number
         buffer.put((byte) ((seqNumber & 0xFF00) >> 8));
         buffer.put((byte) (seqNumber & 0x00FF));

         //timestamp
         buffer.put((byte) ((timestamp & 0xFF000000) >> 24));
         buffer.put((byte) ((timestamp & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
         buffer.put((byte) ((timestamp & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
         buffer.put((byte) ((timestamp & 0x000000FF)));

         //ssrc
         buffer.put((byte) ((ssrc & 0xFF000000) >> 24));
         buffer.put((byte) ((ssrc & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
         buffer.put((byte) ((ssrc & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
         buffer.put((byte) ((ssrc & 0x000000FF)));

         buffer.put(data, offset, len);
         buffer.flip();
         buffer.rewind();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RTP Packet[marker=" + getMarker() + ", seq=" + getSeqNumber() +
                ", timestamp=" + getTimestamp() + ", payload_size=" + getPayloadLength() +
                ", payload=" + getPayloadType() + "]";
    }

}
```